# AS3 - Output what object has keyboard focus?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, keyboard, focus

I'm having a problem with AS3 and keyboard focus, and I'm wondering if there is a variable or a function I can use that will output to screen the name of the object that currently has keyboard focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it through the FocusManager. Then you can simply call the getFocus function.
I put together a quick example that shows the current focus every second, really meaningless as it is, but it shows you how it works:

```
import fl.managers.FocusManager;
var focus:FocusManager = new FocusManager(this);

function traceFocus():void
{
    trace(focus.getFocus())
}


setInterval(traceFocus,1000);
```

Just put this code in the root and then some input boxes on the stage and it should work.
Also, check out [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/managers/FocusManager.html)

Answer (score 1):

This works as well:

```
if (stage.focus) { trace (stage.focus.name); }
```

Note that if you're using a TextInput component and expecting its name when the user clicks on it, you will actually get the instance name of the child TextField of the TextInput (which will have an arbitrary name like *instance88*), so you should use **stage.focus.parent.name** to get the right instance name of the TextInput itself.